# get the results of each item on runtime without waiting all the loop

Tags: vb.net, foreach, listbox

Here is my code:

```
    For Each itema In ListBox3.Items
        Dim source As String = getsource(itema)
        If source.Contains("blz blz blz")  Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add(itema & "====> here is one")

        Else
            ListBox2.Items.Add(itema)
        End If

    Next
```

How can I get the result of each item without waiting for the loop of all items in vb.net??
In PHP there is the flush and ob_flush to flush the memory.

Comment: For those who know VB.NET, but do not know PHP, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this asp.net or winforms?

Answer (score 0):

If this is windows forms you can use the `.Refresh()` method (`Listbox2.Refresh()`) or if you use windows forms you can use `.InvalidateVisual()` method(`Listbox2.InvalidateVisual()`)

Comment: InvalidateVisual() is not the right way to do this, and it won't do anything until his code returns anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your items to add one by one, you need to "return" and let it process the message-pump after each item so WPF can update the UI.

You can either code this the hard way, by splitting up your code into multiple Invoke() functions, or you can use Async/Await. The latter looks something like this code below. The `await Task.Yield()` returns control to the WPF message pump.

```
Async Sub MyFunction()
    For Each itema In ListBox3.Items
        Dim source As String = getsource(itema)
        If source.Contains("blz blz blz")  Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add(itema & "====> here is one")
        Else
            ListBox2.Items.Add(itema)
        Await Task.Yield()
    End If

Next
```